# What traits are implemented by an array

Tags: rust

I am trying to find out more about the array data type, specifically what traits does it implement and where do methods like `len()` and `iter()` come from. What other methods can I call for an array? I am not sure if this a SO appropriate question. But, after two days of researching I am not any wiser.

```
let arr = [0i, 1i, 2i];
let l = arr.len(); //What trait am I using here for the len() call?
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your case, `arr` is of type `[int, ..3]`, a reference to which can be coerced to `[int]` automatically. Thus, any methods on `&[int]` work.

For the full list of relevant things: http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/slice/primitive.slice.html